# Angular material datatable checkbox keep value in array when Select all or select single item and remove if unselect

Tags: checkbox, angular-material, angular7, angular-datatables

When user select master checkbox all values must be push to array. Value must splice from array when user unselect specific checkbox and push again to array if select again. Here is my sample code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4tkjyi). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few mistakes in your code, notably that you didn't check for the correct property on the `MatCheckboxChange` event. You checked for the `check` property, when it is actually called `checked`, see [here](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api#MatCheckboxChange).

Also you tried to use `splice` with a `string` (the `name` property of the current `row`) and `number` argument, when in fact it takes `number, number`.

A proper IDE would notify you of these mistakes and help you solve them.

> [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4tkjyi-5izsjk?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.ts)
>   is a working version of your table.

Comment: Working as expected. Thanks @fabian

Comment: how to indetify if any checkbox is checked?

Comment: To see whether 1 or more checkboxes are checked you can use `this.selection.hasValue()`.

Comment: I did that. Where is the best place to do checking? Currently I have implemented like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4tkjyi-fudmmj

Comment: Last one, where we can check if master checkbox is checked?

Comment: It is right there in the template: `[checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"`.

Comment: can u answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272345/angular-7-material-select-all-checkbox-in-datatable-not-working

Comment: You are saviour! thanks Fabian.